# Why kill [pid] does not work?

Tags: kill, pid

I face a problem trying to kill a pid. I have a ruby pid that i try to kill but nothing happens.

```
lsof -i   (service list)
```

ruby      282 xxx    3u  IPv4 0xffffff80111f4c20      0t0  TCP localhost:49206 (LISTEN)
ruby      282 xxx    9u  IPv4 0xffffff800fa29c20      0t0  TCP *:hbci (LISTEN)
ruby      282 xxx   10u  IPv4 0xffffff80115406c0      0t0  TCP localhost:hbci->localhost:49400 (ESTABLISHED)

```
kill 282
```

The same things

```
ps -A | grep ruby
```

282 ??         0:24.54 /xxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/ruby-debug-ide-0.4.17.beta14/bin/rdebug-ide
  324 ttys000    0:00.00 grep ruby

```
kill 282
```

still nothing.

May be someone faced already this issue?

Comment: you can try kill -9 pid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

kill -9 pid should work. Kill neads a signal to send (-9 = SIGKILL).

Answer (score 1):

See [THIS](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-kill-unix-process-with-kill-command/) for usage of the 'kill' command. You must send a signal to the PID ID to tell it why it is closing. Also, make sure that you are killing as root.